# Is it correct to use "media" as a plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> There are six **media** widely used: newspapers, radio, TV, books,
>   theater, comics.

To be specific, is it correct to place the number six right before "media"?

Comment: You should probably say "...books, theatre **and** comics."

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  *Media* may be used as a collective noun, but it is also used as the plural of the countable noun *medium.*

I have noticed that the people who write curatorial texts in art museums seem to prefer the plural *mediums* lately, but that just makes me think of tarot cards and crystal balls.

Comment: I thought that five kinds of media should have been used instead of five media in this context. I assume that five media/mediums does not mean five kinds of media.

Comment: @TerryLi What is a "kind of medium"?